# Spring Boot Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mysql-connector

Actually i'm developing a restful API
with spring boot
and I use insomnia as a client to test the modifications made on my entities.
When running the application with tomcat an error message is displayed:

---

> FAILED TO START APPLICATION
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class.

I made the necessary configuration in the file "application.properties"
and I did add the dependencies for the mysql and JPA connector in the pom.xml file.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hm2z.png)

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you post your mysql related dependencies in your POM? When looking at [the available dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql) it looks like not every one of them includes a driver.

Comment: You can (and shall) inline the screenshot image in the question, this way it's easier for the community to see immediately. Welcome on SO!

Answer (score 0):

you can test your application.yml validity ,I also meet this problem
the question:
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: add some space to your properties.yml , that's will be ok ;